# Croppie, base64 image, transfer to node.js via $http, multipartyMiddleware

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using `croppie` to alow user to crop image.

`Croppie` returns base64 encoded image (in my understanding a string with encoded image data).

Since I am using `Angular 1` I want to transfer such an image using `$http` component.

This is my approach:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.croppieRun = function () {
        croppieObject.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            format: 'png',
            size: { width: '300', height: '300' }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            var imgData = resp.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

            factory.sendImage(imgData);

        });
    }
```

**Factory:**

```
function sendImage(imgData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: prefix + "/album/photoAdd",
        headers: {
            data: imgData
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**node.js server**

```
router.post('/album/photoAdd', requiresUserAuthentication, multipartyMiddleware, function (req, res) {
var file = req.files.data;
```

I can see some reasons why it is not working myself:

- server is not prepared to get `POST` headers of this size, I would need to change some settings there and I would prefer not doing it
- I guess `multipart/form-data` encoding should be used not `base64` to allow usage of `multipartyMiddleware`on server side

What is the best approach to this problem?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to post image data as `data` in POST not as one of `headers`